# Parsing and indexing documents with Apache Tika

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, apache-poi, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse and index .doc files into elasticsearch with apache Tika.
Actually, my project is to build a resume search engine for my company.

Since we have a standardized resume format, I would like to parse these resume using apache tika in Java.

Basically I have a .doc file like this :

```
   Jean Wisser                                           avenue des Ternes
                                                          75017 Paris
   Business Intelligence Consultant

   Skills : Qlikview, SAS, Cognos, ...
   Companies : IBM, Orange, ...
```

And I would like to extract and parse the content to index it in elasticsearch like this :

```
 XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder()
    .startObject()
        .field("Name", "Jean")
        .field("Lastname", "Wisser")
        .startObject("Adress")
                .field("Street", "avenue des Ternes")
                .field("City", "Paris")
           ......
           .endObject()
    .endObject()
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?
Should I use Tika, POI or something else ?

Comment: Do the different parts of your word file have different styles applied to them? Or is it just all random / no styles?

Comment: Yes, they have different styles but I don't know how to extract them.
When I extract the content with tika I only get plain text

Comment: How are you calling Tika? Tika will happily give you XHTML if you ask it correctly!

Comment: when I get XHTML it only gives me basic <b> or <p> tags which are not really reliable because sometimes people forget to put titles in bold or keep the same layout as before.
Instead I use regex to identify blocks in my resumes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand well your question, but If you want a tool that can help you to extract information corresponding to each type of information in the '.doc' file, Tika can't do that for you automatically (if they are not already in the metadata of the document), but you need to prepare your data first (extract the text and write your own program to parse and extract data). Once you have extracted the data, you can index the document with the fields needed.

Comment: Yes ! That's exaclty what I want to do but I have no idea what should I use to parse my .doc file.

Actually I had in mind to convert my file in XHTML using Tika and then use something like XPATH to extract my fields.
Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: well, first, before thinking about indexation, think about extracting the information needed. You can read your document line by line and you can help yourself with some regex to extract data you need . For exemple, if the line starts with "Skills :" the rest of the line is the list of skills. You can also use regex to extract the adresses or use GATE (General Architecture for  Text Engineering) to extract adresses from your documents and save the results in an xml file if you want.

Comment: For persons names, if the first line of all your documents starts with a name of a person, it should be easy for you to extract it. If not, you need to use Stanford NER for entities recognition. NER will give you the list of person's names existing in a text. NER can also Extract name of campanies, but i think in your case, a simple search for the line starting with "Companies :' is enough for you to get the list of companies in your document.

Comment: For you suggestion, I don't think XHTML will help. But you can try :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually I wanted to use XHTML because Tika can parse any file format into XHTML, so if I receive another file format (.pdf, ...) I will always have a standard XHTML input for my parsing method.

Comment: Why don't you juste extract the text from you document (pdf, doc, ...etc) with tika and treat the text?

Comment: Do you know how to extract text with tika mapper-attachment plugin of elasticsearch??

Comment: Yes yes I know how to extract plain text with tika. I think you are right, there is no point to convert the files in XHTML. I'm actually completly new to text-mining. And I juste figured out that even the "standardized" files that I need to treat  sometimes don't have the same structure, so I think basic regex will not be enough and I will need to use more complex tools like GATE or NER

Comment: OK :) Great! if you need help tell me.